# Django can not access Image and Media files

Tags: python, django

When I upload my files on my server I'm getting errors (not found error) while loading images and media files. But on my computer (localhost) everything is ok. Can you help me to fix?

> settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/site/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

MEDIA_URL = '/files/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('article.urls')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> templates/index.html

```
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <!--image-->
            <canvas class="image-canvas" style="background-image: url({{ article.cover.url }});"></canvas>
            <div class="caption">
                <!--article head-->
                <h3 style="text-align: center !important;">{{ article.title }}</h3>

                <!--article summary-->
                <div class="content"><p>{{ article.content | truncatewords_html:'30' }} </p></div>

            </div>
            <div class="visible-xs line "></div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Check STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT path and upload_to attribute in cover field.

Comment: checked. no problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Do you use apache2 with Django?

If yes, did you specify to apache2 where the static and media folders are located

```
<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

---

*old answer:*

Do you set right permissions on folder media?

the ugly way to do that

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/media/
```

the good way

```
sudo groupadd djangogroup
sudo adduser www-data djangogroup
sudo chgrp -R djangogroup /var/www/
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/
```

Comment: I put ls output for static file

Comment: Did you use -R to change the permissions to files in folders? Try sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/static/

Comment: I edited my answer. Did you specify to apache where static and media folders are located?

Comment: I'm using nginx

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls -al static/

drwxrwxr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 24 17:01 css
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 24 17:00 fonts
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 24 17:01 img
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 24 17:01 js
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 24 17:01 partials
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 24 17:01 scss
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx you have to configure where the static and media files are located.
I've used this tutorial to configure nginx + uwsgi + django:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Specifically refer to [this](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configure-nginx-for-your-site) section of the tutorial

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your settings.py check for Debug option if it is set to False.
this should be set to true if you want to access files using
if settings.DEBUG: